# Amazon S3 Unable to find credentials in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image file to `aws s3` storage and get back that image `URL`. I'm using secret key and access key to create credentials. But when the program runs it it says

> "Unable to find credentials" .

Here is my code which i used.

```
    public string sendMyFileToS3(string from,string to, string bucketName, string fileName)
    {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(bucketName, fileName);
        AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);
        TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
        TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
        request.BucketName = bucketName;
        request.Key = fileName; 
        request.FilePath = from; 
        utility.Upload(request); 
        string urlString = "";
        GetPreSignedUrlRequest request1 = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = fileName,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2)

        };
        urlString = client.GetPreSignedURL(request1);
        Console.WriteLine(urlString);

        File.Move(from, to);

        return urlString ;
    }
```

Comment: Which line of code is generating the error? In which region are your services?

Answer (score 11):

In order to create an S3 Client you need to provide your credentials, the region and endpoint:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com";
config.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");
client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
```

The possible regions are listed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region), and depend on where you created your bucket being `us-east-1` the default value.

While the possible endpoints are this three:

- s3.amazonaws.com
- s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com
- s3-accelerate.dualstack.amazonaws.com

The first one being the standard one since the others need you to configure your bucket like it's explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html#transfer-acceleration-getting-started).

Comment: ServicURL is optional if you have the region https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Config_ServiceURL.htm

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess and say you have a conflict between the credentials your app is using and other credentials you may have installed onto your dev or test machine, i.e. in the credentials file or your app.config.

I would check and make sure you are only using a single method to provide those credentials to the program.

THis link shows the priority the SDK will look for the credentials:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html